# cron job for running a script based on db value

Tags: cron

I had a sctipt runthisapp.sh and I am having some dates in my db table holiday . My problem is every day it should check the db ,if the date is present in holiday table runthisapp.sh should run at 10'o clock 
Else
It should run at 8'o clock.
I had tried but can't find the solution .Can you.help me.on this please

Answer (score 0):

You can have two crontab entries, one at 8am, one at 10am, passing different options to your script, e.g. the former takes `--holiday=0`, and the latter `--holiday=1`, and your script should just return doing nothing if in the wrong "holidayness".

Comment: @user2281038 if you find an answer helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it